# TypeError: '_curses.curses window' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, terminal, ubuntu-16.04, curses

This is my code and I don't know why I'm getting error when I run this program on terminal.this is my python code python 3.5, I'm new to curses module and unable to  handle this error ,thanks in advance

```
import urllib.request as ur
import time
import curses

def ini(i):

  url       = 'http://www.top4themes.com/data/out/134/6545537-superman-logo-wallpapers.jpg'
  req       = ur.urlopen(url)
  count     = 0
  block_size= 1024
  avg       = 0
  smin      = []
  value     = False
  t         = []

  while True:
    start   = time.time()
    buff    = req.read(block_size)
    stop    = time.time()
    avg    += len(buff)

    if not buff:
        break;

    if (stop-start) < 0.2 : 
        block_size += 2048

    elif (stop-start) > 0.2:
        block_size -= 1024

    count += 1
    stdscr(1,0,"{}".format(block_size))
    stdscr.refresh()
    t.append(int(block_size))

    if(block_size ==0):
        block_size=max(t)

 if __name__=="__main__": 
    stdscr = curses.initscr()
    curses.noecho()
    curses.cbreak()
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            ini(i)
            time.sleep(0.5)
    finally:
        curses.echo()
        curses.nocbreak()
        curses.endwin()
```

Comment: Please add to the question your full error message with its traceback, so that we know which line exactly it was raised on (and during which sequence of calls).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error refers to the line `stdscr(1,0,"{}".format(block_size))`. Presumably you were going for something like `stdscr.addstr(1,0,"{}".format(block_size))`.